# SELECT all which share an id (of a list of ids) with another entry without using subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

*I'm struggling to give this question a good title. If you can help me out, please do. Thanks!*

---

I have a table with two fields:

```
UserId | ProjectId
```

Each is a key to another table that I will use in some joins later.

As an example, I want to get all `UserId` that share a `ProjectId` with `UserId = 1`

I've created an [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27ec7/2). It uses the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE UserProject
    ([UserId] int, [ProjectId] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO UserProject
    ([UserId], [ProjectId])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 5),
    (3, 6),
    (4, 5),
    (4, 6),
    (5, 5),
    (5, 7),
    (6, 8),
    (7, 1),
    (7, 6)
;
```

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [UserId] FROM [UserProject] WHERE [ProjectId] IN (
  SELECT [ProjectId] FROM [UserProject] WHERE [UserId] = 1
);
```

This accomplishes the task, but I was trying to come up with a solution that doesn't use a subquery. I was also hoping to avoid using `IN()` if possible.

#### Questions

- If possible, how can this be done without using a subquery?
- If possible, how can this be done without using `IN()`?
- Is a subquery the optimal way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  others.UserID
FROM
  UserProject   AS target
INNER JOIN
  UserProject   AS others
     ON others.ProjectID = target.ProjectID
WHERE
  target.UserID = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27ec7/4

Comment: Excellent! I think I was looking at this from the wrong angle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct up1.userid
from
userproject up1
inner join
(
SELECT userid,projectid
from userproject
where userid=1  
) as up2

on up1.projectid=up2.projectid
```

Comment: This is still a subquery, isn't it?